# Linq get array and sum as part of the returned dataset

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I have this Linq query:

```
var result = from game in db.Games
                    join gameevent in db.Events
                        on game.GameId equals gameevent.GameId
                    join birdLife in db.EventBirdCaptures
                        on gameevent.EventId equals birdLife.EventId
                    select new
                    {
                        game.GameId,
                        game.Name,
                        gameevent.LocationId, - array of all the location id's based on the game id
                        birdLife.BirdId - sum of all the birdids based on event id
                    };
```

For the last two results, location id and bird id I want to get array of the id's for the location id and the sum of bird ids.

How is that possible to be achieved in Linq?

Comment: Please add some input and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you are asking, but if I understand what you want you can use `join-into` (group join) instead of `join`:

```
var result = from game in db.Games
             join gameevent in db.Events
             on game.GameId equals gameevent.GameId into events
             from _event in events
             join birdlife in db.EventBirdCaptures
             on _event.EventId equals birdlife.EventId into birds
             select new
             {
                 game.GameId,
                 game.Name,
                 locations = events.Select(e => e.LocationId),
                 birds = birds.Sum(b => b.BirdId)
             };
```